# How to read yml file uploaded to aws s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a yml file containing certain credentials and keys. So for extra security I wondered if it would be good to upload it to s3 and access using the private url or via aws object.

I tried giving the url in my development.rb to load the file which didn't work.

Next I tried creating an aws object and access the file in the s3 bucket.

```
s3  = AWS::S3.new(access_ key_id:  'xxx',  secret_access_key: 'yyy')

s3.buckets['my-bucket'].objects['file_name.yml']
```

I tried putting the url, file name without .yml to get access to the file and read it. But it keeps returning me empty `{}`. Does this have anything to do with url/file permission?? How can I achieve this?

This is the first time I am using aws and am not sure if my approach is correct or if this is the best way to keep sensitive data safe. Plz guide me on how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Why would it be more secure to host it on S3? This in my mind would only generate one extra attack path. If someone gets hold of your source code they would get your access_key and be able to acquire your other secrets anyway?

Comment: if you are using aws-sdk v1 you can do something like yfile=YAML.load(bucket.read) and then you will be able to access the keys of the yml file by doing yfile['secret_access_key'] for example... hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following gem for this, much better than yaml implementation.

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

install it and add to to you Gemfile.

then `vim .env` or create this new file using editor of your choice.

Add your keys:

```
S3_BUCKET=YOURS3BUCKET
SECRET_KEY=YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE
```

and save it.

You can now call it from your application wherever you need the S3 keys.

```
ENV['S3_BUCKET']
ENV['SECRET_KEY']
```

Once its pushed to Heorku, just updated your environment variables, no need to push your secrets to Github.